# Is "She's a corrigible flirt" a proper positive form of "She's an incorrigible flirt"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> 1. She’s an **incorrigible** (incorreggibile) flirt.
> 2. She's a **corrigible** (correggibile) flirt.

In Italian language "incorreggibile", used like in "1" case, is a 'negative' word for which, strictly speaking, the 'positive' form doesn't exist.

In fact, in Italian language one cannot use the "2" sentence because it sound awkward. I'm not sure why, but I think that this happens because "1" example is a bit idiomatic.

Furthermore, always with regarding to Italian language, I'm not able to think of another word, different from "correggibile", that can express the 'positive' form of "incorreggibile".

So, I'm wondering if, in English language, "corrigible" can be used to express the 'positive' form of "incorrigible" in "2" case. If not, does another word exist? Or, in this case, are English and Italian similar?

Comment: NOAD lists both words, and gives them opposite meanings. However, it seems like _incorrigible_ is [much more popular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corrigible%2Cincorrigible&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) than _corrigible_. I don't know if that's a quirk of the English language (perhaps due to idioms), or a reflection of human behavior. :^)

Comment: Vices, errors and manuscripts are all *corrigible*. The real question is: What circumstances would give you occasion to speak of a *corrigible flirt*? "My girlfriend is a corrigible flirt; she stops when I ask her to/smack her around a little" is probably not going to come up all that often.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Corrigible* literally means correctable, while *incorrigible* literally means uncorrectable.  From this, you might conclude that the two words are opposites.

However, most speakers don't think of *incorrigible* as defined in terms of *corrigible*.  In fact, I would venture to guess that many speakers aren't familiar with the word *corrigible* at all!  The two words have their own idiomatic patterns of usage, and they don't correspond in manner or frequency.

If you did say *corrigible flirt*, I think it would be interpreted in one of two ways:

1. unidiomatic or incomprehensible; or
2. wordplay, coining the word anew as a [back-formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_formation) from *incorrigible*.

This sort of wordplay happens all the time, as when people re-invent the word *gruntled* (from *disgruntled*).  It works because *gruntled* is an obsolete English word few people are familiar with.  Likewise, *corrigible* is relatively unknown, and though it's not quite obsolete, it isn't generally used in this fashion.  Because of this, I'd expect *corrigible flirt* to be interpreted as either novel or mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing grammatically or semantically incorrect about "She's a corrigible flirt". Here's a [quote from a 2008 handbook on law](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22corrigible%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en), which I found using Google Ngram Viewer:

"The first dimension represents the evaluation of the options from the perspective that **the offender is corrigible**, and the second dimension represents the evaluation of the options from the perspective that **the offender is incorrigible**." [My emphasis.]

(from *Blackwell Handbook of Judgment and Decision Making* [p 139])

Most instances of *corrigible* are, as kiamlaluno says, not used for people but for errors or institutions.

In the 2006 book *Presbyterians Being Reformed: Reflections on What the Church Needs* (p. 69), the author says: *The church is corrigible.*

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on *corrigible flirt*, but *corrigible* means "capable of being corrected, rectified, or reformed"; its meaning is the opposite of *incorrigible*, which is used when a person is not able to be corrected.

The only difference I can see is that *corrigible* is not necessarily used for a person (or it is not used for a person).

Comment: kiamla, for example, "Sei proprio correggibile!" is not the opposite of "Sei proprio incorreggibile!" in Italian language, no?

Comment: For those who don't understand Italian, "Sei proprio correggible!" literally means "You are just corrigible!"

Comment: ... or "You are *so* corrigible!"

Comment: _Correggibile_ is the opposite of _incorreggibile_. I am not sure somebody says _sei proprio correggibile_ in Italian. _Sei proprio incorreggibile_ is the more used sentence.